# Disable CORS / CORB across react app without having nodeJS / Express server

Tags: html, reactjs, heroku, cross-origin-read-blocking

Trying to launch an app on Heroku that fetches a response from Okta but i'm getting a CORB error

Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response https://dev-493904.oktapreview.com/oauth2/default/v1/keys with MIME type application/json.

Is there any way to just enable the response to come through without creating a Express and NodeJS server?

I can't see any Webpack server settings I can alter to change the headers.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you **need** a backend server to make requests that have CORS protection. You could try serving your code using a [simple python server](http://2ality.com/2014/06/simple-http-server.html)

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

but odds are you are going to need to implement CORS compliant requests.

Additionally, I would check if Okta has some sort of code sample for doing this in the frontend and you could copy that directly.

An easy way to do a sanity check is to try the request in [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) and use its code generation feature to try a successful request in your own codebase.

Comment: What i'be found is its only in chrome it works fine in firefox. Its not a "CORS" error per say its a CORB on the response i get back from the API  ( its a JSON object ). It's so frustrating.

Comment: @ChristopherForrest — Sounds like you are trying to make a JSONP request. JSON is not JSONP and attempting to make a JSONP request for JSON will generate a CORB error.